# Selenium webdriver IsTextPresent (on the page more than once)

Tags: c#, text, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium web driver to determine whether a string of text exists more than twice on a page, as it should only appear once.

I can use Assert.IsTrue(this.Driver.IsTextPresent("body", "string")), but I was looking for a while to see if the text was on the page more than once.

Comment: This is in java but it shows how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442895/how-many-times-a-text-appears-in-webpage-selenium-webdriver It seems the only way is to get the text using getText() and then parse the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with `FindElements`:

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'TEXT')]")).Count;
```

If `Count > 1`, then the text is present more than once on the page.